# grabbing first result set from a stored proc called from another stored proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2005 stored proc which returns two result sets which are different in schema.

Another stored proc executes it as an Insert-Exec. However I need to insert the first result set, not the last one. What's a way to do this?

I can create a new stored proc which is a copy of the first one which returns just the result set I want but I wanted to know if I can use the existing one which returns two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to Result sets from within Stored procedures Transact-SQL SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, INSERT..EXEC will try to insert BOTH datasets into the table.  If the column counts match and the datatype can be implicitly converted, then you will actually get both.

Otherwise, it will always fail because there is no way to only get one of the resultsets.

The solution to this problem is to extract the functionality that you want from the called procedure and incorporate it into the (formerly) calling procedure.  And remind yourself while doing it that "SQL is not like client code: redundant code is more acceptable than redundant data".

In case this was not clear above, let me delineate the facts and options available to anyone in this situation:

1) If the two result sets returned are compatible, then you can get both in the same table with the INSERT and try to remove the ones that you do not want.

2) If the two result sets are incompatible then INSERT..EXEC cannot be made to work.

3) You can copy the code out of the called procedure and re-use it in the caller, and deal with the cost of dual-editing maintenance.

4) You can change the called procedure to work more compatibly with your other procedures.

Thats it.  Those are your choices in T-SQL for this situation.  There are some additional tricks that you can play with SQLCLR or client code but they will involve going about this a little bit differently.

Comment: I am aware of that point and like I said, the two results sets have schemas. So no, both can't be inserted into the same table.

I need to do it the way I explained so that if someone modified the first proc, the second proc automatically gets the proper data returned by the first proc. Copying the sql is not a good idea because then a developer has to modify both at the same and developers will miss the dependency. This is not a redundant data case. It's redundant code which is bad.

Comment: Please re-read my Answer, everything that you bring up is covered there: 1)You can-NOT get only one of the sets, 2)They must be the same schema to get both, 3) there is no way around this, 4) your best alternative is to copy the code.  The only other alternative is to change the called procedure to be more compatible.  These are you r only choices.  I am sorry, but that is how SQL works.

Comment: Optionally, you can just add a parameter to the stored procedure that returns multiple result sets that you can use in an IF/ELSE statement to cause only 1 result set to be returned.  I.e. we have a sproc that we pass a parameter called "resultType" and it returns different result sets based on resultType, that way we don't have to have redundant logic in multiple sprocs that has to be maintained in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a compelling reason why you can't just have that first sproc return only one result set? As a rule, you should probably avoid having one sproc do both an INSERT and a SELECT (the exception is if the SELECT is to get the newly created row's identity).

Comment: The first sproc is an existing one and already in production.

As to your rule you mentioned, there's nothing wrong with a sproc doing whatever it needs to do its work. Multiple inserts and selects in one sproc is very common. You didn't explain what are the disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Oo to prevent code from getting out of synch between the two processes, why not write a proc that does what you want to for the insert, call that in your process  and have the orginal proc call that to get the first recordset and then do whatever else it needs to do.

Depending on how you get to this select, it is possible it might be refactored to a table-valued function instead of a proc that both processes would call.

Comment: Original proc can't and should not be changed for this purpose. It's a complex one and should not be touched just because another proc wants the same data. The reason I didn't want to copy the code because it a mile long and it will be very convenient if I can just call it in my proc in a single statement.

If anything, I have to come up with a solution which reuses it without modifying it.