# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Inserting into tables from child procedure which returned multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a child procedure which returns more than table.

child:

```
PROCEDURE KevinGetTwoTables
AS BEGIN
    SELECT 'ABC' Alpha, '123' Numeric

    SELECT 'BBB' Alpha, '123' Numeric1, '555' Numeric2
END
```

example:

```
PROCEDURE KevinTesting
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
        Alpha varchar(50),
        Numeric1 int
    )
    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
        Alpha varchar(50),
        Numeric1 int,
        Numeric2 int
    )

    --INSERT INTO @Table1
    EXEC KevinGetTwoTables
END
```

Comment: Put a question mark in here or people will freak out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to capture both result sets in the parent procedure, like you could with a single one into a temp table.  However, there are several other options.  Read the excellent article [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables).

If you are using SQL Server 2008 look at the section on [Table Parameters and Table Types](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#tableparam).  You can pass the tables as output parameters, back to the parent.

If you are not on SQL Server 2008, look at the [section on Sharing a Temp Table](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables).

You basically create two #TempTables in the parent procedure, and in the child procedure you populate each of the #TempTables and terminate the child procedure.  When you are back in the parent procedure each #TempTable has data in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to capture a second result set inside T-SQL.

You could do it from a [CLR stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server/879516#879516).

Comment: Using the CLR is good if you can't change the child procedure:  http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#CLR