# Querying the resultset of a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to query the result set of a stored proc?

I only have execute permission on a stored proc and when I run the stored proc, it shows millions of rows. I need to query the result set of the stored proc.

What would be the efficient / simplest way?

FYI,I use SQL Server 2012.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Comment: If adhoc distributed queries are enabled you can use [`OPENROWSET`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005435/73226). The most efficient way would be to write a query that only returns exactly the data you need though.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try using openrowset.

Comment: Martin, I don't have access to the tables. I've to query from the stored proc result.

Comment: Well the other option if openrowset doesn't work is to `insert ... exec` the results into a table variable or temp table then select from that.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what the results look like, then you can put them into a table.  First create the table and then use `exec()` or `exec sp_executesql`.

For example:

```
declare @lines table (id int identity(1, 1) primary key, line varchar(8000));

insert into @lines(line)
    exec sp_executesql N'sp_helptext ''information_schema.tables''';

select *
from @lines
order by id;
```