# Accessing 2nd table in dataview

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a sqlDataSource that runs a stored procedure that returns a table of the days of the month that was passed in as a parameter, arranged as they would in a calendar. It also returns a second table which contains the event details associated with certain days of the month.

Basically, how would I go about accessing the values contained in the 2nd table that is returned by my query?

I have tried putting the result of the .select in a dataset, unfortunately I get a cast error. If I try to put it in a dataview, I only get the first table.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I have right now:

```
  Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
  Dim eventTable As New Data.DataTable
  ds = sqlCalendrier.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
  eventTable = ds.Tables(1)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you can do what you want to do.  Split it into two separate stored procedures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server

Comment: That's what I feel also. I'll keep my hopes up that someone has a solution/idea for this, but I'll start planning out a 2nd option with the guy that manages the database/procedures. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Get in through the backdoor:

1. Get the dataview returned by the
   Select statement
2. Get the table associated with this
   dataview
3. Get the dataset associated with the
   table

Code example:

```
Dim dv As DataView = CType(sqlCalendrier.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
Dim ds As New DataSet() = dv.Table.DataSet
Dim dtDates As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
Dim dtEvents As DataTable = ds.Tables(1)
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

By using the tables collection of the data set instance

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds = <your data source>
    Dim dtDates As New DataTable()
    Dim dtEvents As New DataTable()

    dtDates = ds.Tables(0)
    dtEvents = ds.Tables(1)
```

Comment: That's what I have and it gives me a conversion error on the ds = <your data source> line. I'll add the code I have in my question

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-to-access-stored-procedures-with-adonet/1058831):

```
 With cmd
   .CommandText = "ProdsAndCusts"
   .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 End With


 cn.Open()

 myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

 While myReader.Read()
   ...

 End While


 myReader.NextResult()

 While myReader.Read()
   ...

 End While
```