# retrieve result set from a stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve the first result set from a stored procedure,
this procedure returns tow result set And I need the first one only 
How Can I do it ??

```
for example : 

   -- the first result 

        -----------------------------------------
        | ID | Code | Name | Notes | .... | ... |
        -----------------------------------------
        |    |      |      |       |      |     |

   -- the second result
        -----------------
        | Date | Number |
        -----------------
        |      |        |
```

Comment: Check this thread:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to change the Stored Procedure code, you could add an Optional SQL Parameter, like:

`@FirstOnly bit = 0`

Then after the first `SELECT` statement, have the following query:

```
IF @FirstOnly=1
BEGIN
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: You're write, But I don't want to alter the Procedure
I'm looking for solution with out alter 
But if I didn't find I will use your solution
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edit the stored procedure and delete/comment the second result.

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary table. execute the sql procedure and insert result into the temp table and select the first row. so you won't have to alter the procedure.

Comment: I think OP is after the first result set, not the first row