# Handling Multiple Results in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure with input parameters which returns two result sets.

Out of the two result sets, I have to fetch the second one through the query. Could you please help with this?

Comment: AFAIK that's impossible to do with pure t-SQL. I remember looking for a solution for this a few years back and came up with nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to Result sets from within Stored procedures Transact-SQL SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server) You will see in the accepted answer it's impossible in pure t-sql, but in the second answer you will see it can easily be done using an sql-clr function.